# RSelenium $getElementText does not parse table correctly

Tags: rselenium

I am trying to scrape a table in a dynamic web page:

```
library(RSelenium)
driver<- rsDriver()
remDr <- driver[["client"]]

url.fv.op <- "http://www2.aneel.gov.br/aplicacoes/capacidadebrasil/capacidadebrasil.cfm"
remDr$navigate(url.fv.op) # navigates to webpage
click <- "body > font > table:nth-child(8) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(1) > font > a"
load_page <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", value = click) 
load_page$clickElement() # Web page that contains the table of interest, with 8 columns

xpath <- "/html/body/table[2]"
elemX <- remDr$findElement(using="xpath", value=xpath) # get big table in text string
dataX <- elemX$getElementText()
dataX[[1]]
```

The table of interest has eight columns (see comment in code above). However, the output in `dataX[[1]]` only recognizes the first column througth the separator `/n`, and put in the same string all the following seven columns. 
Any hints on how to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution:

Delete :

```
dataX <- elemX$getElementText()
dataX[[1]]
```

and add:

```
hlink<- read_html(elemX[[1]]$getPageSource()[[1]] )
table <- html_table(hlink,fill = T)
tf <- table[[2]]
```

`rvest` functions do the trick.